# Arduino Serial Logging A String & Variable To Single Line

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I'm an Arduino newbie.  I'm somewhat running before I'm walking.  I want to output my "state" variable to the serial console.  This works, however the state is on a different line to the text:

```
Serial.println("State set to ");
Serial.println(state);
```

So my output is like this:

> State set to
>
> 1
>
> State set to
>
> 0

However, when I try to get the output on a single line using this:

```
Serial.println("State set to " + state);
```

I get output as follows:

> tate set to
>
> State set to
>
> tate set to

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Glad to help, might you upvote the question as well so that others might find it easier? Thanks!

Comment: Done! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead:

```
Serial.print("State set to ");  // .print makes no linefeed...
Serial.println(state); // linefeed after you're done
```

This will achieve the effect of printing on one line.  Reference is [this Arduino forum post](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=41444.0).